# Join two tables not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL statement, see below. I'm not sure how i can put in another table. I have tried a few things but it all appears back as errors. 
What i need is to display items from two tables. They are two seperate tables, only thing is in common is Date in both.

Can someone help me?

```
$value = $_GET['id']; 
             $dbQuery = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Appointment INNER JOIN Results WHERE Date=:value");
             $dbParams = array(':value'=>$value);
             $dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you are not using prepared statements correctly.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a `from` in there?

Comment: all corrected. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing the ON operator for your join.  The other problem is that you don't specify *which* `Date` is being used in your where condition.  It is not much of a difference in code, but the below snippet should resolve the problem with your join, and for more on joins [follow this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
$value = $_GET['id']; 
$dbQuery = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Appointment INNER JOIN Results ON Appointment.Date = Results.Date WHERE Results.Date=':value'");
$dbParams = array(':value'=>$value);
$dbQuery->execute($dbParams);
```

Comment: Thank you for finally providing a proper answer, after two answers completely devoid of explanation and code formatting.

Comment: Nice answer, but you shouldn't concatenate data to a query, or what's the point from using prepared statements?

Comment: @MehdiBounya I agree and upvoted the comment that you added to the OP's question.  I was just trying to address the problem that the OP wanted addressed.  I thoroughly agree that proper use of prepared statements is important and should be looked into by the OP.

Comment: @mtr.web OP already fixed his code in the answer, even if he didn't, you should encourage good practices for future readers.

Comment: @Anna, [here is a place to research prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) @MedhiBounya, The ambiguous `Data` in the where statement wasn't fixed in the OP's question, but I see your point.

Comment: @mtr.web hi thanks for this. it seems that if there is no date to be found for the results table it will  not show anything. I need results to show for both even if one tables date doesnt have any data??

Comment: @Anna.  The join statement is only going to return values that have a value for Date in both `Results` and `Appointments`, as dictated by the `INNER JOIN`.  This will be the case unless you have another common field.or you did a `left join` and used `Appointment.Date` in place of `Results.Date`.  That would still require a value for `Appointment.Date`

Comment: @mtr.web ok i thought this! is there any way i can do the sql statement which returns values for both regardless whether it matches? Does this mean i need to just do two seperate SQL statements?

Comment: @mtr.web I edited your answer with a little update, hope you don't mind

Comment: @Anna, unfortunately you have to have a common column between the two tables to do a join, and unless there is another column you can use, it will have to be the Date column.  You could add an `ID` column in `Appointment` that corresponds with a column like `AppointmentId` in `Results` and use that for the join.  This would return both `Date` values without requiring them to match.

Answer (score 1):

If multiple tables in a query have one or more field names in common, those field names must be qualified with the name of the table (or alias used for the table if there is one).

Also, your query lacks a join condition, so if Appointments.Date was specified (alone), you'd get every appointment for that date paired with every single row from the `results` table.

Answer (score 1):

You need use ON to communicate two tables

```
SELECT * FROM Appointment as a
INNER JOIN Results as r
ON a.Date = r.Date
WHERE r.Date=:value
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp